# Match a target spectrum

Tags: audio, signal-processing, spectrum, acoustics

I'm working on rolling noise emissions from cars. 
I have a model for rolling noise emissions which gives me sound pressure levels in third octave bands (29 in total, between 20Hz and 8kHz), depending on vehicle speed, and road/tyre combinaison.

I'd like to fit a real recording of tire/road noise to the model, while keeping the spectral properties of the recording. The signal of rolling noise is mainly stochastic

[image]

In blue, the spectrum of the recording using Welch's method, and in red, the levels i'd like to reach.

What kind of methods can i use in this particular case?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Not a programming question - try http://dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite dependent on the structure of the model you're trying to fit, but you should be able to use an optimization method (such as `fmincon` in MATLAB) to adjust the model parameters until you reach an acceptable level of error between your measurements and the model.